# Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce Revenue

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

We have two list.One of them is bestsellers and the other is recently viewed. We added an item with id 23456 from the bestsellers list. 
On add to cart event we are sending the details correctly as list name- "bestsellers".

Now while doing a checkout we added the same item with id 23456 from the recently viewed list. Here also On add to cart event we are sending the details correctly as list name- "recentlyViewed".

But after completion of checkout, the revenue for both the items(One from bestsellers and the other from recentlyViewed) is getting added for the recentlyViewed list.

Kindly please  guide what should be done is such cases.

Comment: Have you confirmed that bestsellers and recentlyViewed aren't both getting sent?  I recommend using the GA Debugger chrome extension to view what is being sent to GA.

Comment: While add to cart event the list name is sent correctly from our end i,e when bestsellers then bestsellers and when recentlyViewed then recentlyViewed.

Comment: Do you have a link that you can share?